# python -- vscode -- pycharm does not have ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages in sys.path

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pycharm

When I run the following code in PyCharm, VsCode and Terminal I get different output

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

Running this in terminal gives

```
['/home/vijayvithal/scripts',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/vijayvithal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
```

With VS Code and PyCharms `/home/vijayvithal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages` is missing!

What settings do I need to modify for the two IDE's to pick up the .local folder?